# Pentaho - Accessing Same CDE Dashboard By Different Users with restricted data

Tags: pentaho-cde

I have a requirement, where the dashboard has the sales report of different regions. If 'User1' logs into server, he should see only his region data, for e.g: canada, if 'User2' logs in he should see only his region data,e.g: washington.. I wonder how this could be achieved using CDE.?. Please can anyone share your thoughts ..?

Regards,

Abdur Rahmaan

Answer (score 2):

You have to manage the relation between your users and the regions they can see in a table. If you have a lot a users, consider to group them by roles and manage in your table the relation between the roless and the regions.
In a dashboard, you can get the current user and its roles with Dashboards.context (or better in you are in version 5.4 or later : this.dashboard.context).

Comment: I use 5.3 version, where can i find Dashboards.context..?. Also give me some sample syntax on how to modify the query.

Comment: You should learn at least the basics for building dashboards. There are tutorials on the web